# HTTP Range header without corrupting mp4 file

Tags: video, rendering, mp4, video-processing, video-encoding

I want to preview mp4 files from http server so I want to request a small part of them. each file has different encoding. How can I do that without corrupting the file, so the file will be viewable?

Note: I can access any part of the file with the HTTP Range header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with FFmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i http://example.com/foo.mp4 -t 00:01:00 -c copy outfile.mp4
```